# Select by .attr quiz

Tags: jquery

I want to create a simple quiz. Any word fits into the text field, and if the word is correct, a class is set that changes color. Spent a lot of time. Please help correct the error!

```js
var answer = $('span').attr('data-answer');
  var submitted = $('input').val();
  $('.submit').on('click', function () {
  if (answer == submitted) {
    $('input').addClass('correct');
  } else {
    $('input').addClass('incorrect');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-answer="text2">
  <input type="text" id="A">
</span>

<span data-answer="text1">
  <input type="text" id="B">
</span>

<button class="submit">Check Answer</button>
```

Comment: The whole code and logic is flawed. You are reading the data-answer of 2 different spans into one variable! You are reading the val() of 2 inputs into one variable! and you are doing this BEFORE/outside the click handler of submit button!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to loop through each span and grab it's data-answer and the child input.

```js
  $('.submit').on('click', function () {
  
  $('span[data-answer]').each(function(){
    let input = $(this).find('input');
    input.removeClass();
    if ($(this).data("answer") == input.val()) {
      input.addClass("correct");
    }
    else{
       input.addClass("incorrect");
   }
  });

});
```

```css
.correct{color:green;}
.incorrect{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-answer="text2">
  <input type="text" id="A">
</span>

<span data-answer="text1">
  <input type="text" id="B">
</span>

<button class="submit">Check Answer</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand my mistakes! Why did you use let, not var?

Comment: You can think of let as local and var as global. Its more nuanced than that though.